# Linq to objects: if number is in dictionary, return number, else return 0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have a `Dictionary<int int>`. When I check the keys of the Dictionary for a number and it is in it, I want it to return the number, else I want the linq query to return 0.

Something like the following, except working

```
var t = (from result in results
         where result.Key == 3
         select result.Key != null ? result.Value : 0).First();
```

Because the problem is that when there is no number in the list, the sequence contains no element, so you can't check with a null or a count.

Comment: I can't tell from your example, but if you are always storing the same key and value `(key == value)`, then you can use a `HashMap<int>`.

Comment: What it is, I'm working on an F1 app and this part should store a position along with the points for that position. Points can change though (although this is more in matter of years).

Comment: Sorry, couldn't edit my comment. I meant to say: What it is, I'm working on an F1 app and this dictionary should store a driverId along with the points for that driver. The driverId is the key, and the value is the points a driver scored. I will only store the first 10 drivers (FIA rules).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `TryGetValue`.

```
int i;
results.TryGetValue(3, out i);
```

If it finds it, `i` is set to the value.  If not, `i` is default, which will be zero for int.

If you want another value besides default, you can do this:

```
int i;
if (!results.TryGetValue(3, out i))
{
    i = 5; // or whatever other value you want;
}
```

And if you, like me, hate the `out` parameter style, you can create an extension method

```
public static class IDictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
    {
        T i;
        dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

and then you can call:

```
int i = dictionary.GetValueOrDefault(3);
```

and if you want to get fancier you can create another oveload of the extension:

```
    public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue)
    {
        T i;
        return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out i) ? i : defaultValue;
    }
```

which can be called

```
int i = dictionary.GetValueOrDefault(3, 5);
```

Comment: This is pretty neat. But what would you do when you want another value than the default value?

Comment: @Garth Marenghi, I added a bunch of other examples and helpers.  Good question.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just

```
var t = results.ContainsKey(3) ? results[3] : 0;
```

and bypass the need for LINQ altogether?

Comment: Why do two lookups when you can do just one?  This is exactly what `TryGetValue` is made for.

Comment: @Samuel: Well yes, `TryGetValue` would work here, but it's a little clumsy to use (because of the `out` parameter, which has to be a predeclared variable, and can't be a property). In the general case, it's even more annoying to use if the desired default is not `default(T)`. Also, I doubt that one extra lookup is going to affect performance significantly.

Comment: I updated my answer with an extension method that resolves your understandable dislike of `out` parameters.

Comment: @Samuel: +1, I like your extension method

Answer (score 2):

```
return results.ContainsKey(key) ? results[key] : 0;
```

Comment: Why do two lookups when you can do just one? This is exactly what TryGetValue is made for.

Comment: Samuel: That's true, I'll go ahead and give you a bump.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `results` is your dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int int> results = new Dictionary<int,int>{{1,1},{3,3}};
int value;
results.TryGetValue (4, out value);
return value;
```

`value` is `0`, because `TryGetValue` sets it to `default(int)`, which of course is `0`.

You can use linq if you want to type more, confuse people reading your code, and slow things down.  This won't use the hashcode, so it is a slow lookup Big O(n).

```
var t = (from result in results
      where result.Key == 3
      select result.Key != null ? result.Value : 0).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Results is indeed my dictionary. This dictionary should store a driverId along with the points for that driver. The driverId is the key, and the value are the points a driver scored. I will only store the first 10 drivers (FIA rules), so for all the other drivers my method should return a zero

Answer (score 0):

Try `var t = (from result in results where result.Key == 3 select result.Value).FirstOrDefault();`

Now, either you have a match in the where clause, so select will project the correct value, or you have an empty sequence. FirstOrDefault() then either returns the value (if it exists) or 0 (The default for integers.)

Comment: This is semantically different than what the OP asked for.  The code should return the value at `key` if the dictionary contains `key` else 0.

Comment: @Ed S. this will work.  It's super inefficient, but it will work.  It'll loop through the results, fine the one where key is 3, and return the value of that one.  If it doesn't find any, it'll return default, which is 0.  It's correct.  Silly though because we're treating the dictionary as a list unnecessary, but it's what the OP asked for.

Comment: What it is, I'm working on an F1 app and this dictionary should store a driverId along with the points for that driver. The driverId is the key, and the value is the points a driver scored for a particular race. What do you mean with Silly though because we're treating the dictionary as a list unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

Select the value out and then:

```
ToArray().FirstOrDefault()
```